# Marker clusterer calls zoom_changed event of the map twice

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using this third party library, called Marker Clusterer with the Google Maps API. http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

I am trying to trigger an event when the map's zoom level is changed. The odd thing I've noticed though, is that when you click on a marker cluster, it calls the zoom event twice. Has anyone come across this odd error before? Why would it trigger the zoom callback twice? When I zoom normally without using clusters, the zoom callback is only called once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that behavior is [a fix for an issue on IOS](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/detail?id=170).  You can download your own copy of the code and remove the additional call to fitBounds if you don't need it.